# Filtering array with value from Observable/subscribe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to translate keyword through my app, including a list of tags. User should be able to search through them in any language.

Previously I was doing

```
this.tag_array_filtered = this.tag_array.filter(tag => 
   tag.toUpperCase().includes(this.tag_searched.toUpperCase()));
)
```

but it only search the key word, not through translations.

this is how I get a translation from a key

```
this.translate.get(tag).subscribe(value => {
   console.log(value);
})
```

the variable `tag_array`is an array of key, ready to be translated. `tag_searched` contain the user input. `tag_array_filtered` is the array of key (not translated) to be displayed

What I want to do: (not working obviously)

```
 this.tag_array_filtered = this.tag_array.filter(tag => 
    this.translate.get(tag.toUpperCase()).subscribe((value: string) => {
      value.includes(this.tag_searched.toUpperCase())
  })
 )
```

How can I filter my array while transforming the value with a subscribe ? I want to compare each value translated from the array to the user input.

I could do it with hand-made loops I guess but if there is a solution already existing it would probably be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The `translate.get()` method also accepts an array of strings.
You could try like this. The final output will be an object which you could transform it into an array if needed.

```js
let tag_array_filtered = this.tag_array.filter(tag => 
 tag.toUpperCase()
    .includes(this.tag_searched.toUpperCase())
    .map(e => e.toUpperCase())
this.translate.get(matching_tags).subscribe((values: {}) => {
  this.tag_array_filtered_object =  values
})
```